# Portable python script: Is it possible to include third party libraries in script?

Tags: python

I have a Python script which uses open source third party libraries for geoprocessing (OGR and Shapely). My plan is to execute this script on a computer without having to install the required libraries.

I know that there are tools such as py2exe available for this purpose. However, compiling an executable file is not my first choice as I noticed that such files can get pretty large in size. Besides, I would like to use the code within another script. I would therefore like to create a portable python script which already includes the third party methods needed for executing.

Is it possible to include third party methods in a Python script in order to avoid the installation of third party libraries? And if not, what can I do instead, besides compiling an executable file? I work on Windows OS.

Comment: Distribute the library files with your script?

Comment: Use a docker container?

Comment: It is not advisable to do this.
1. Those libraries will be dependent on other libraries, and you end up with a huge list of libraries that you need to supply along with your code.
2. Now your code is bound to the particular version of library that you used. So if the library updates, the users of your code will not be able to benefit from it.
3. You will become responsible for any bugs in your code as a result of a bug in the library since you are supplying the library code along with your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your libraries using pip and embbed them into your application.

pip wheel requires the wheel package to be installed, which provides the "bdist_wheel" setuptools extension that it uses.

To build wheels for your requirements and all their dependencies to a local directory:

```
pip install wheel
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

At this point check requirements.txt, clean it up, then you can download wheels in a local folder :

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

And then to install those requirements just using your local directory of wheels (and not from PyPI):

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

Then though you'll need pip, though it's shipped with latest versions of python.

Check this : https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files

Comment: I find this to be the most convenient solution to my problem. Adding third party methods to a script without installing the actual library not very practical. Local wheels are a good alternative for my project. I experienced that this solution works better than just copying the source files to my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your third party lib does not have any dependencies you can get the source files (.py) put into your project folder and use it as package by using import, else it has dependencies your project size grow more better create exe for your script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested this and it works with one of my two geoprocessing libraries. However, I didn't investigate why the other library caused problems (maybe further dependencies?). In such cases, it is probably best to compile an executable file from my script and the third party libraries. I agree.