# Import a library into a Python file

Tags: python

I wanna ask you if it is possible to copy a library code into my python file so on new computer It will not be necessary to download that library again.

Example:
I am drawing something python using tkinter. I wanna run this program on another where there is not tkinter library. So is is possible to copy the code from library into my python file?
The result should be a python file that uses its own builtin library. So it will not need any library to download?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Portable python script: Is it possible to include third party libraries in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747073/portable-python-script-is-it-possible-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-scrip)

Comment: You can use e.g. Pyinstaller to create fully standalone apps from Python projects. Tkinter is not an extension module that you'd download separately, so in general it's not installable separately either.

Comment: Also I would discourage this, you can copy the entire library files and store this with your files. You of course need to adapt all includes of this lib and you would need to also copy all dependent libraries of your lib (ex. tkinter).